# TypeFace doesn't work and give some exception

Tags: java, android

when i running my code it makes some exceptions because of the TypeFace 
i have a spinner and  i want it to change the font family when i click any of them 
but it doesn't work .

here is my .java code

```
public class Graduation extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageView imageView ;
    Spinner spinner;
    int fontSizeInt;
    String[]items = { "12", "16", "18", "20", "24", "28" , "30" };
    Spinner spinner1;
    int fontSizeFamily;

    String[]f_items = { "Times New Roman ", "Arial", "sans-serif", "20", "24", "28" , "30" };
    EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.graduation);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                    int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                    try
                    {
                        fontSizeInt = Integer.parseInt(items[position]);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        fontSizeInt = 12; // Default size.
                    }
                    et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) fontSizeInt);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            }
        );

        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, f_items);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                          int arg2, long arg3) {
                    int position = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

                    try
                    {
                        if (position == 0 )
                        { 
                            Typeface f = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),"font/TimesNewRoman.ttf");
                            et.setTypeface(f);
                        }
                        if (position == 1 )
                        {  
                            Typeface f = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),"font/arial.ttf");
                            et.setTypeface(f);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        // 
                    }

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            }
        );
        addListenerOnImageg1() ;
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    }

    public void addListenerOnImageg1() {
        final Context context = this;
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.g1);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, g1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context , g1.class); 
            intent1.putExtra("fn" , et.getText().toString());
            intent1.putExtra("font_size", fontSizeInt);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and this is my logcat

```
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858): java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at com.example.invitationcard.Graduation$2.onItemSelected(Graduation.java:92)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:882)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:848)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 12-09 22:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i don't know where is my problem 
also i have xml file wih no error .. has spinner and et and everything defined in .java file ...

also i change my statement to this :

```
Typeface f = Typeface.createFromAsset(Graduation.this.getAssets(),"font/TimesNewRoman.ttf");
```

and it give the same error .. what can i do ?

my .ttf files  exist in bin/assets/font folder .

and the extension of my file is correct .

Comment: if you are using eclipse, assets folder will be in root directory means it is not available in bin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. I'd suggest to check your font file, it might not supported in android or corrupted.
You can try with any other font file or just open your .ttf file in android file system to check it's compatibility.

Comment: You can transfer ttf file on you sdcard and then open it in android file browser.

Comment: can you suggest a link to download files from ?

Comment: You can search, there are several free fonts sites available.

like https://www.google.com/fonts

Answer (score 0):

You can use your View's `getContext()` method to get the current Context, then use it to get the assets:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/arial.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Typeface f = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"font/Blue Highway.ttf");
```

Use getApplicationContext(). This is working at my place.If its not working in you project then there is problem in your ttf file

Answer (score 0):

Create the given two typeface object bellow setContentView method and use it inside spinner

Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/TimesNewRoman.ttf");

Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/arial.ttf");

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there is a problem with the font itself. That error will be triggered when native code in the OS attempts to load the typeface as there is different message for missing file, so I think it is finding the file but not liking it for some reason.

Try using some other ttf file probably download it from some other destination and try to have otf extension of font if possible.